# How do I get Codenameone 2.0 from my IDE?

Tags: codenameone

I understand Codenameone 2.0 has been released. When I updated the plugin from my IDE, the plugin version on Netbeans says it is version 1.0.68? Is this the 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

The plugin version has nothing to do with the version of Codename One.

Codename One versions are mostly a code stabilization milestone that can then be used in [versioned builds](http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---get-repeatable-builds-build-against-a-consistent-version-of-codename-one-use-the-versioning-feature.html). Since Codename One is a cloud service you are effectively always using the latest version of Codename one unless you explicitly use a versioned build.